# Jquery pickatime: call javascript function when value is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm totally new to jquery and a month or so new to javascript. I'm trying to use this jquery package: https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js and I've got the following html:

```
    <input type="text" name="timepicker" id="timepicker" >
    <form id = "order-form" action="confirmation.php" method="POST" >
     <input class = "formitem" type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value="">
     <input class = "formitem" id="next" type="submit" value="Next">
```

Basically, I want to call the sendTime() function to set the 'time' element and click the 'next' element below when the timepicker is set:

```
function sendTime(){
            date = new Date(document.getElementById('timepicker').value);
           document.getElementById('time').value = date;
           document.getElementById('next').click();
        } 
         var $timepicker = $('#timepicker').pickatime(
          {

            min: [9, 0],
            max: [19, 30],
          }
          );
```